# Mysql connectiong two tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Right now i have these two tables

doctor_id and their appointment count

[image: doctor_id and their appointment count]

and doctor name and his/her department name

[image: doctor name and his/her department name]

I need to count every department appointments any idea how to connect these two tables ?

Comment: Are you dealing with views that you show or do you have original tables used in queries you show?

Comment: First of all, welcome. Second thing is, you need to post out table structure, sample data and tried MySQL query in text form, not images. Much better if you can create a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: funny nomenclature
`Ear Nose and Throat` = laryngology
your `departaments` = specializations

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: What does "connect these two tables" mean? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When it is clear it will likely be a faq.  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join all the tables and change the grouping.

```
SELECT d.name AS department, COUNT(r.d_id) AS appointment_count
FROM departments AS d
JOIN userdelprel AS ud ON d.dept_id = ud.dept_id
JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = ud.u_id
LEFT JOIN roomreservations AS r ON r.d_id = u.u_id
WHERE u.role_id = 2
GROUP BY d.dept_id
```